# Get value from textarea in bootbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, bootbox

I have a bootbox.dialog with a textarea. I want to save the value of the textarea with rowbrakes in the same place as it was written to the database. So I need to create a string with `/n` or `<br>`.

Right now is my value undefined.

Here is my code:

```
$('#btnComment').click(function () {        
    var comment = $("#lblComment1").html();
    popup.dialog({
        title: translator.get('EditComment'),

        message: "<textarea cols='60' rows='6' name='editComment'>" + comment + "</textarea>",

        buttons: {
            confirm: {
                label: translator.get('EditComment'),
                className: "btn-success",

                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result === null) {

                    } else {
                        $("#editComment").val(result);
                        $("#lblComment1").html(result);                            

                        var ajaxData = {
                            Type: "Comment",
                            OrderId: $("#lblOrder").html(),
                            newValue: $("#editComment").val(),
                            MiddocID: $("#hidMiddocID").val()
                        }

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: configuration.baseUrl + '/api/OrdersPostback', //
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                        }).then(function (bResult) {
                            if (bResult) {
                                $("#editComment").val(result);
                                $("#lblComment1").html(result);
                            }
                        });
                        //$("#hidBtnComment").click();
                    }
                }
            },

            cancel: {
                label: translator.get('Cancel'),
                className: "btn-default"
            }
        },


    })

});
```

Any suggestions of what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `<textarea>` into this:

```
message: "<textarea id='editComment' cols='60' rows='6' name='editComment'>" + comment + "</textarea>",
```

Note that I've added the `id="editComment"` which you didn't do in the first place. Now that element will be fetchable by `$('#editComment')` and you can use `.val()` and other jQuery methods/plugins.

Comment: Thanks. But later in the code when i makes "ajaxData" the result is:

Object {Type: "Comment", OrderId: "P000389", newValue: "[object Object]", MiddocID: "OC150909132737235"}

Comment: I don't see anything... result is what?

Comment: I saw it was the result i had inside "$("#editComment").val(result);". When i deleted it, ive got the value right. 

But next problem is to save the rowbreaks in the textarea?

Comment: You mean the new lines?

Comment: Yes, when i save the text its important that all new lines will be saved and when the text is loaded from the database the label will display the text with all the correct linebreaks

Comment: You use PHP on the server side and do you store that value in a MySQL database table?

Comment: Im not using php. Its c# and i found that "text.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br />');" worked like i wanted. So now the function is working. Thanks for all the help

Comment: The replace works when i saves it. But when i load it and will edit it again in textarea, i cant found out how to replace the "<br />" with simple linebreaks? I want the "<br/>" to be unseen. How can i do that?

Comment: Try with: `text.replace('<br />', /\n\r?/g);`.

Comment: When i take text.replace('<br>', '\n'); it will only replace the first <br> not all . Do you know why?

Comment: Are you using `text.replace('<br>', '\n');` in JavaScript (client-side) or in C# (server-side)?

Comment: I found the answer and it was this:

text.replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g, '\n');

Comment: Yes. That should do it. You're replacing the `<br>` or `<br />` globaly now with `"\n"`. By the way, I strongly suggest you use `"\n"` (double-quoted) instead of `'\n'` (single-quoted).

Answer (score 1):

```
var dialog = bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a textarea!",
    inputType: 'textarea',
    callback: function (result) {
        if (result ) {
            console.log (dialog.find('textarea.bootbox-input-textarea').val());
        }
    }
});
```

you can get the value by textarea class "bootbox-input-textarea"
http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#prompt-option-input-type